# How do i ask if a variable is empty for example if the user just presses enter(python3x)

Tags: python-3.x

for example
x is an int

```
if x==(user presses enter without value input)
y=1
```

How do i get the code to accept that value?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you would read an empty string in that case. An empty string is [*falsy*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), so you can use the following:

```
if not x:  # i.e. if "user gave no input"
    ...
```

You should perform that check *before* parsing `x` as an int.